# Integration between Supersonic ADS and Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, ads, supersonic

I'm trying to use Supersonic ADS inside my app written in xamarin (ios and Android)

Is there any way to include it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They have a Unity plugin that works on iOS and 'Droid  so they have the C# wrappers for their native libraries.. I would send them a request about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have an iOS and/or Android SDK, you can create a [Xamarin Binding Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) to allow you to use the Native library from within your Xamarin project.